Abstract index notation - can't understand identity $(dx^{\mu})_aT^b\partial_bv^a=T^b\partial_b[(dx^{\mu})_av^a]$
I'm trying to get familiar with abstract index notation. Came across this identity:
$$(dx^{\mu})_aT^b\partial_bv^a=T^b\partial_b[(dx^{\mu})_av^a]=T^b\partial_bv^{\mu}$$
where $T$ and $v$ are vector fields, and the $\partial$ operator is defined as follows for a $(1,1)$ tensor field (this can be generalized to arbitrary rank tensors:
(in abstract index notation) $$\partial_aT^b_{\ \ \ c}=(dx^{\mu})_a\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}\bigg)^b(dx^{\sigma})_c\partial_{\mu}T^{\nu}_{\ \ \ \sigma}$$
(in standard notation based on my understanding)
$$\partial T=\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}T^j_{\ \ \ k}\bigg)dx^i\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\otimes dx^k$$
The identity in question can be proved in standard notation as follows (to equate LHS of the identity to the first expression below, I'm using the shortcut that for a vector and covector field $X,\omega$, we have $\omega_aX^a=X^a\omega_a=\omega(X)$):
$$dx^i(C[T\otimes\partial v])=dx^i\bigg(C\bigg[T^j\partial_kv^l\partial_j\otimes dx^k\otimes\partial_l\bigg]\bigg)=dx^i\bigg(T^j\partial_jv^l\partial_l\bigg)=T^j\partial_jv^ldx^i(\partial_l)=T^j\partial_jv^i$$
But I am struggling a bit with proving the first equality in the identity with abstract index notation version. Would appreciate any help.

Where exactly did you come across this? Abstract index notation can be understood when we know what our tensors are. In your case $dx^\mu,T,v$ are tensors but what is $\partial v,?$ Did they mean $\nabla v,?$

@KurtG. Sorry I should have specified properly. $\partial$ is a special type of derivative operator. i.e. it has the usual properties of $\nabla$, and additionally its action on a tensor is defined via the equation I gave in the question. I hope that clarifies it a bit

You did not tell me where exactly you came across this. Your post contains four unnumbered equations. It is hard to tell which of those you consider to be the definition of $\partial,.$

@KurtG. The book's name is Differential Geometry and General Relativity by Liang. Equation 2 is the definition of $\partial$ in abstract index notation. Equation 3 is the same definition in standard notation. Equations 2 and 3 are equivalent. Also, if you have access to this book, the definition is mentioned on page 72.

Not sure what extra details or clarity this question needs - seems self-contained to me. If I can get some inputs, let me know and I'll edit the question to include required details.

After accepting the answer do you still want more? In that case the ball is in your court. BTW: abstract index notation is an arcane niche subject that was introduced to bring back to the coordinate-free tensor world what was the simplest operation of all in coordinate-based component notation: contraction. In your case we contract the tensor components $$\delta^\mu{}\eta,T^\sigma(\partial\rho v^\nu)$$ over $(\eta,\nu)$ and $(\sigma,\rho)$ which gives without fancy concepts $$ T^\sigma(\partial_\sigma v^\mu),.$$

Obviously it does not even matter what $\partial$ is. Any fifth-order tensor $A^\mu{}\eta{}^\sigma{}\rho{}^\nu$ can be contracted this way.

@KurtG. "After accepting the answer do you still want more?" Yes, I do. After editing the question and clarifying details I expect a question to be re-opened, and I'm glad that it has since then. "abstract index notation is an arcane niche subject" - you have more knowledge in this area so you know better, but I thought AIN is widely used in general relativity literature..

For the life of me I can't see an edit  in the time line of that question that you claim to have made. I am happy to give you more but need to know exactly what is still unclear.

Unfortunately the version of that book in google stops at p. 66.
So I start from some principles that are tersely explained, say, in
Wikipedia.
If $\boldsymbol{v}=v^\nu\partial_\nu$ is
a vector field then
$$\tag1
dx^\mu\otimes \boldsymbol{v}=v^\nu dx^\mu\otimes \partial_\nu
$$
is a $(1,1)$-tensor. Let's view it as a linear combinations of the
basis tensors $dx^\mu\otimes \partial_\nu\,.$ Each of those has
components $\delta_\mu{}^\nu\,,$ and in abstract index notation:
$$\tag2
dx^\mu\otimes \partial_\nu=
(dx^\mu)_a (\partial_\nu)^b\,
$$
where $a,b$ label the slots. The contracted tensor $(dx^\mu)_a (\partial_\nu)^a$ is a scalar which is the trace of $\delta_\mu{}^\nu\,.$ Hence,
$$\tag3
(dx^\mu)_a (\partial_\nu)^a=\delta^\mu{}_\nu\,.
$$
By linearity it follows that the contracted $dx^\mu\otimes\boldsymbol{v}$ is
$$\tag4
(dx^\mu)_a(\boldsymbol{v})^a=v^\nu\delta^\mu{}_\nu=v^\mu\,.
$$
This explains the last equals sign in your first identity.
To see the first equals sign I write the LHS uncontracted:
$$\tag5
dx^\mu\otimes \boldsymbol{T}\otimes \partial\boldsymbol{v}
$$
I believe that $\partial\boldsymbol{v}$ is the $(1,1)$-tensor
$$\tag6
(\partial_\rho v^\nu)\,dx^\rho\otimes\partial_\nu
$$
where $\partial_\rho$ is the ordinary partial derivative.
When $\boldsymbol{T}$ is a vector field then (5) is in abstract index notation
$$\tag7
(dx^\mu)_a\,\boldsymbol{T}^b\,(\partial\boldsymbol{v})_c{}^d\,.
$$
In standard notation this is
$$\tag8
T^\sigma(\partial_\rho v^\nu)\,dx^\mu\otimes\partial_\sigma\otimes dx^\rho\otimes\partial_\nu
=\delta^\mu{}_\eta\,T^\sigma\,(\partial_\rho v^\nu)\,dx^\eta\otimes\partial_\sigma\otimes dx^\rho\otimes\partial_\nu
\,.
$$
The contraction
$$\tag9
(dx^\mu)_a\,\boldsymbol{T}^b\,(\partial\boldsymbol{v})_b{}^a\,.
$$
is the vector that has components
$$\tag{10}
\delta^\mu{}_\nu\,T^\sigma(\partial_\sigma v^\nu)=T^\sigma(\partial_\sigma v^\mu)\,.
$$
This is the RHS of your identity. So the proof is complete.

Also posting my own understanding here, for future reference and as help to anyone else reading it (by "Liang" I mean the book Differential Geometry and General Relativity Vol. 1 by Liang, and by "Newman" I mean Semi-Riemannian Geometry by Newman):
First note that $$\partial_b((dx^i)_av^a)=(dx^i)_a(\partial_bv^a)+\partial_b((dx^i)_a)v^a=(dx^i)_a(\partial_bv^a)\tag{1}$$
$$=(dx^i)_a\big(\partial_jv^i(dx^j)_b(\partial_i)^a\big)=\partial_jv^i(dx^i)_a\big((dx^j)_b(\partial_i)^a\big)\tag{2}$$
where $\partial_b((dx^i)_a)=0$ (see Liang pg. 72 eq. 3.1.10). Converting the tensor part of the last term to math notation,
$$(dx^i)_a\big((dx^j)_b(\partial_i)^a\big)=C^1_1[(dx^i)_a\otimes((dx^j)_b\otimes(\partial_i)^c)]$$
$$=C^1_1[(dx^i)_a\otimes (dx^j)_b\otimes(\partial_i)^c]=(dx^j)_b$$
where for the 2nd equality, we used (Newman pg. 99, Th. 5.1.2 - see lines immediately after that theorem too). Thus the last term in eq. (2) is $\partial_jv^i(dx^j)_b=\partial_bv^i$ (see Liang pg. 56 eq. 2.6.3). This justifies the 3rd equality in the last equation on Liang pg. 80.
For notational convenience I can denote $\partial_bv^a$ as $S_b^{\ \ a}$ so that $(dx^i)_aS_b^{\ \ a}=S_b^{\ \ i}$ , which in turn equals $\partial_bv^i$.
$T^bS_b^{\ \ a}$ in math notation is $C^1_1(T\otimes S)=C^1_1[T^iS_j^{\ \ k}\partial_i\otimes dx^j\otimes\partial_k]=T^iS_i^{\ \ k}\partial_k$.  (for last equality see Newman pg. 107 Th. 5.4.3). Translating this back to abstract index notation, we have $T^iS_i^{\ \ k}(\partial_k)^a$, or $T^iS_i^{\ \ a}\equiv T^jS_j^{\ \ a}$. So the LHS of pg. 80 last eq. is:
$$(dx^i)_a(T^bS_b^{\ \ a})=(dx^i)_a(T^jS_j^{\ \ a})=T^j(dx^i)_a(S_j^{\ \ a})=T^b(dx^i)_a(S_b^{\ \ a})=T^b\partial_b((dx^i)_av^a)$$
where the last equality follows from eq. (1) of this post. With that we've fully justified Liang - pg. 80 last equation.

The authors and titles of the books you quote should be edited into this answer.

@KurtG. Thanks for the heads up! I've edited the answer with the full book name

You mentioned two books: Liang and Newman.

@KurtG. Edited.
